# Problems with hyperlink in table row

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table rows `<tr>` generated by a loop (PHP). I have transform a entire row in a link, but the problem is a `<input type="checkbox">` on the row. Every time I check the box the page redirect because the `data-href` on the `<tr>`.
What i want to know is if there is a way to block or stop the checkbox to redirect and the checkbox continue working normally?

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="active-row" data-href="../my_link/file.html">
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>Note Note</td>
        <td>9171690</td>
        <td>$156,80</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".active-row").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

SOLUTION(EDIT):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $(".active-row :checkbox").click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
   $(".active-row").click(function () {
      window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
   });
});
```

Comment: You're setting the hyperlink as a property of the *whole* table body. Depending on what you want I suggest you redesign where you want that hyperlink.

Comment: ok... thanks for the ideia!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "catcher" click to the checkbox first and then add the other click handler:

```
$(".active-row td input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".active-row td").click(function(e) {

    window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
});
```

Comment: nice... very nice, @Axel it works perfectly, exactly as expected. I only made some adjustments but it works!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventDefault()` in your `jQuery` code like the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".active-row").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();            
    });
});
```

Comment: Only problem I have with this is that the link doesn't work anymore, but thanks for the ideia.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check current clicked item like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".active-row").click(function() {
            if(!$(this).is(':checkbox')){
                 window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
            }
        });
    });
```